# clearing an entire column in access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

is there a way to clear an entire column in a datasheet in access? i can just right click on it and delete it but that will affect the structure, i just need to clear all the records. how do i do this?

perhaps the question i should be asking is how do i clear the entire contents of a datasheet in access?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

right click on upper left square of the datasheet, click DELETE RECORD

Comment: Okay, I'm confused. Which do you want to do, clear a column or a record?

Answer (score 8):

Use an update query, e.g.

```
UPDATE YourTable 
SET YourColumn = NULL
```

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this directly from the UI, which kind of makes sense.

See

- [Update data by using a query - Microsoft Office Online](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/update-data-by-using-a-query-HA010076527.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE table_name
  SET field_name = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler: right click on the column header in access, select copy.  Now go to excel and paste into a excel column.  Now hit the delete key, then copy that.  Go back to access right click column header and paste.  Done.

Note: When selecting what to copy in excel may want to exclude column header or may get extra blank record.

Answer (score 1):

Use Replace All function for CURRENT FIELD, FIND WHAT = * and REPLACE WITH = blank.  Took 10 seconds to blank out 22600 records.  Make sure you LOOK IN = CURRENT FIELD and that field is highlighted.